# How do i reassign the contents of a variables?

Tags: python, list, variables, drop-down-menu, google-colaboratory

I'm using google colab and dropdown doesn't allow variables to be used within itself.
Therefore, I need that at a certain value in commas, the variable changes to a certain value of the original variable.  It sounds complicated, so it's better to look at the code, everything will become clear there.

```
engine_output_path = '.../engine/'
output_obj = 'apple'

path_var_0 = 'engine_output_path'
path_var_1 = 'output_obj'
path_var_2 = ''
path_var_3 = ''
path_var_4 = 'output_obj'

for i in range(5):
    print(f'path_var_{i}')
    if f'path_var_{i}' == 'engine_output_path':
        f'path_var_{i}' = engine_output_path
    elif f'path_var_{i}' == 'output_obj':
        f'path_var_{i}' = output_obj
        
print(f'{path_var_0}{path_var_1}{path_var_2}{path_var_3}{path_var_4}')

#.../engine/appleapple should appear in the console
```

Also i tried using str() it didn't help

```
for i in range(5):
    print(f'path_var_{i}')
    if 'path_var_' + str(i) == 'engine_output_path':
        'path_var_' + str(i) = engine_output_path
    elif 'path_var_' + str(i) == 'output_obj':
        'path_var_' + str(i) = output_obj
```

UPD
Ok, I see that it is not very understandable what I mean, so now I will explain more and more clearly.
[This is what dropdown looks like in google colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq7Rx.png)

path_var_i (i for index) is a variable. path_var_i = 'user selected value'. However, the value of the variable cannot be another variable, Google leaves no other option than to set the dropdown list ONLY using a string.

```
#This way
engine_output_path = '.../engine'

path_var_0 = "engine_output_path" #@param ["", "output_name", "engine_output_path", "output_obj", "str(cycle)"]

print(path_var_0)
#Will output "engine_output_path" in the console and not ".../engine"
#I need to get exactly ".../engine" in the console
```

Thus, I need to check the value of each variable and return them the value of the original variable and not the string.
[I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9IRa.png)

[Or this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy2Ov.png)

I'm sorry, most likely the mistake is that I don't know how to concatenate the string and the index in the loop

Comment: tell me you desire output

Comment: Use a dictionary; Trying so make variable name from strings is **incredibly bad idea**.

Comment: i dont understand why you can use if statement? you can check if a==b then a=b ? whats the reason behind this i dont understand your logic

Answer (score -1):

To change the value of `path_var_1`, try this

```
globals()['path_var_1'] = 'new value'
```

Or, if you want to use `i`

```
globals()[f'path_var_{i}'] = 'next value'
```

Comment: I'll set once more: This is **VERY BAD IDEA**